# Jooq query to fetch data that are updated in last two days

Tags: database, jooq

I have been using student table which has field called updated_time which stores time in milliseconds.I have to fetch the student record that are updated in last two days using JOOQ query .what is the query for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
ctx.selectFrom(STUDENT)
   .where(STUDENT.UPDATED_TIME.ge(currentTimestamp().minus(2)))
   .fetch();
```

This assumes, as always with jOOQ, that you have the following static imports:

```java
import static com.example.mygeneratedtables.Tables.*;
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```